# Keep track of images captured by user

Tags: android, count, photo

A User takes pictures using camera in his device. My application should keep track of how many photos captured by the user.
I don't want my application to launch any default camera. I want to get count incremented for clicked photos by the user with his device camera.

Since devices having soft button camera not works with `CAMERA_BUTTON` intent, so is there any other way to get count.

Comment: would you like to count the image files in the DCIM instead?

Comment: I want to update count when new image captured by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my application should keep track of how many photos captured by the user

In general, that is impossible. You have no ability to spy on arbitrary actions of other applications.

The closest thing is what julian suggested -- use a `FileObserver` to monitor `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`. However, not all camera applications will store their pictures there.

Comment: But when ever i shut down or unmount the sd card this file observer listening and count increases .duplication occurs.

Comment: @thes: So, do not "track of how many photos captured by the user", unless you write your own camera app.